# Hylafax: Encounter "No font metric information" when try to send a fax

Tags: linux, fax

I am using **Hylafax 6.0.5** on **Fedora 13 x86_64**.  As there are no rpm package available for Fedora 13, I use the source tar ball to install hylafax myself. Everything seems fine during compile and install.

I try to send a fax with **sendfax** and encounter error:

```
# sendfax -n -d <fax-number> /etc/passwd
/usr/local/sbin/textfmt: No font metric information found for "Courier-Bold".
Usage: /usr/local/sbin/textfmt [-1] [-2] [-B] [-c] [-D] [-f fontname] [-F fontdir(s)] [-m N] [-o #] [-p #] [-r] [-U] [-Ml=#,r=#,t=#,b=#] [-V #] files... >out.ps
Default options: -f Courier -1 -p 11bp -o 0
Error converting document; command was "/usr/local/sbin/textfmt -B -f Courier-Bold      -Ml=0.4in -p 11 -s default >'/tmp//sndfaxp5GdJ9' <'/etc/passwd'"
```

It seems like there is problem with font problem. **I have ghostscript-fonts installed too.**

I can't find `hyla.conf` in path `/etc/hylafax`. There is no `/etc/hylafax` path in my file system. All configuration files seems located in `/var/spool/hylafax/etc`.

Comment: Fedora 13 is _long_ discontinued. Consider installing a newer version (or migrating to RHEL/CentOS).

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification **Hylafax**  uses converters in order to transform various types of MIME content find in mails to *Postscript* format, which BTW is the only format that can handle to send fax.

You can find the converters in the `/var/spool/hylafax/mimetype/` directory in a default install. For example for the text (or plain) MIME type you will see there is a file called :

```
text/plain
```

or

```
text/text
```

With the contents of the command to be executed in order to transform the text file to PS.

The error you find is with the `textfmt` command executed in one of those files, so the problem can be solved by giving the correct arguments to the command line you will find in one of the aforementioned files ( `man textfmt`).

You can even use any other utility for converting from plain text to *PostScript* like [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/).

Answer (score 0):

I saw this problem few years ago.
You ve got to install some PostScript files or GhostScript 
and check if there is a Courier-Bold. Also you have to check in what directory hylafax is searching for font files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The solution which worked for me can be found here: http://roeften.blogspot.ch/2010/10/converting-text-files-to-fax-fails.html